# Embed Bing map rotate programmatically

Tags: javascript, bing

Does anyone know how to rotate a embedded bing map in bird eye view with JS?

I tried to click the `.NavBar_rotateRight` element in JS with a `.click()` but it does not respond

this is the API

http://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7#CreateMapWithViewOptions7

ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To rotate the map to the east, you can set the heading property to 90 degree like this:

```
var options = map.getOptions();
options.heading = 90;
map.setView(options);
```

You can only use the values 0, 90, 180 and 270 for heading.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427628.aspx.

Comment: yes this is on embed .. but not after it has been instantiated

Comment: For me it was also working after the map is instantiated. Can you give an example that does not work?